# Automapper Collection Mappings: How to find out if object is Updated or Created

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following code

```cs
        public class AAA
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

        }

        public class BBB
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public int UpdatedOrCreated { get; set; }
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void MappingTest2()
        {

            var _mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddCollectionMappers();

                cfg.CreateMap<AAA, BBB>(MemberList.Destination)
                .EqualityComparison((a, b) => a.Id == b.Id)
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, src => src.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdatedOrCreated, /* set value 2 for Updated or 3 for Created */)
                .ForAllOtherMembers(m => m.Ignore());
            });

            _mapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            var mapper = _mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();

            var varin = new List<AAA>
            {
                new AAA
                {
                    Id = 1,

                },
                new AAA
                {
                    Id = 2,

                }
            };

            var varout = new List<BBB>
            {
                new BBB
                {
                    Id = 1,

                }
            };


            var ttt = mapper.Map(varin, varout);

            ttt.Should().HaveCount(2);

            ttt[0].Id.Should().Be(1);
            ttt[0].UpdatedOrCreated.Should().Be(2);

            ttt[1].Id.Should().Be(2);
            ttt[1].UpdatedOrCreated.Should().Be(3);
        }
```

I am using the Automapper Collection extensions and want to set the field 'UpdatedOrCreated' based on a new object is created or an existing object is updated.
I have not found a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AAA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ValueA { get; set; }
}

public class BBB
{
    public int UpdatedOrCreated { get; set; } = 2;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ValueA { get; set; }
}

public class CustomList : List<BBB>
{
    public new void Add(BBB item)
    {
        item.UpdatedOrCreated = 3;
        base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

```
var varout = new CustomList
{
    new BBB
    {
        Id = 1,
        ValueA = "bang"
    }
};
```

Comment: I was hoping that this can be done without spying on other values but just by checking if a new object was contructed or not(somehow)

Comment: I saw this line in the MapperConfiguration .ForAllOtherMembers(m => m.Ignore());. this line ignore ValueA property

Comment: I removed ValueA from the example.

Comment: Automapper Collection does not create new objects,it only insert the old object reference in the destination list, You can use custom List Model for destination and detect when Add method is fired. Check Edited Answer

Comment: Sorry but it creates new object. In this example it creates a new BBB object with Id = 2. It reuses the existing object when found otherwise it creates a new object.

Comment: rudimenter did you find a solution  ?